# cassandra possible node loss

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, replication, sharding

I am fairly new to Cassandra and found this website
https://www.ecyrd.com/cassandracalculator/
Not sure how accurate it is, but i have one misunderstanding.
Consider following example:

- cluster size 8
- replication factor 5
- read concern ONE
- write concern ONE

As a result i get that I can lose 4 nodes without impacting the application. Does anyone know what calculation leads us to this result? Thanks in advance.
P.S. I would like to remark that I am not interested in any other aspect, except "how many nodes I can loose without impacting application". The answer I am looking for is not how consistency works, or anything else, but exclusively what equation stands behind described result for "how many nodes I can loose without impacting application" and why.

Answer (score 1):

A CL.ONE can always lead to the possibility of data loss. As an example: A replica as the coordinator gets requests, writes locally and sends ack to client. If that system is then hit by a meteor before the data to the other replicas has been sent theres data loss.

If you use local_quorum or quorum then with a RF=5 you can have 2 nodes of the replica set fail without any data loss (excluding cases like not following expected operational practices around repairs). However with CL.ONE your application can still run even if 4 of the 5 replicas died, in some cases availability is more important than the durability and consistency. I would recommend always start with quorum and then only change your consistency if theres an unmet availability of performance requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand part with data loss using write consistency ONE. What I fail to understand is the criteria that is used while calculating amount of nodes i can loose and not impact application. Do you know how it works?

Comment: data loss limit is the number of replicas ack'd on a request. If your request is acknowledged to the client, then all the nodes that acknowledged it die then your application will think a write succeeded but the data is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can tune consistency at query level also based on requirements. 
SELECT * FROM users WHERE state='ABC' USING CONSISTENCY QUORUM; Yes, CL ONE provides good availability than quorum but quorum will give you more consistent data.